# Need to tie application insights to hockeyapp app

Tags: azure, hockeyapp

I'm using hockeyapp on my Android application and I can't seem to tie in the application insights. The documentation says to set the application type of the application insights azure resource to "HockeyApp Bridge Application" but I don't see anywhere to set it.

Here is the documentation I was going off of. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/hockeyapp-bridge-app

Comment: You should be able to do it with any application type now. That's why it is hidden. Thank you for pointing out to this section in a doc!

Comment: But if it is any application type, how do I tie the hockeyapp application to the app insights? Previously there was a field for the HockeyApp API key. Now where would I put it?

Comment: @ZakiMa forgot to tag you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ability to create new apps in HockeyApp that export their analytics data to Application Insights has been removed over a year ago.

Instead, we recommend users to use the new [Export feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/analytics/export) in App Center, HockeyApp's successor product.

*Note: I work on both HockeyApp and App Center.*